# Retrieve Inner Text from WebView HTML in Windows/Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm creating a universal app and need to be able to pull plain text from a HTML page. I know that in WPF you can utilize the IHTMLDocument2 interface to achieve this.

```
IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
string data = document.body.innerText;
```

Is there something similar for Windows Runtime?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack-PCL/). The HTML then becomes queryable through Linq. Then you can do something like this:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = webBrowser1.Document as HtmlDocument;
string innerText = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("body").Single().InnerText;
```

You can also load the HTML as a string or stream through `LoadHtml` and `Load` respectively.